# Acetaldehyde tautomer name

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

Thought it may have been ethylene oxide, but it's not.

Comment: Ethylene oxide has its oxygen atom attached to both carbon atoms making a saturated three-membered ring.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_oxide.

Comment: Learn a bit of IUPAC nomenclature first. Then you dont have to worry about naming.

Answer (score 4):

The IUPAC name is ethenol. It is also commonly called [vinyl alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_alcohol).

Comment: I don't think it's such a good idea to answer such questions. It will probably get closed, it is already downvoted a lot. I don't think that it will be of much help for future visitors, as I doubt it will be found ever again. In the long run it's just a question that dilutes the content. But that is only my personal point of view. (Your positive scoring answer prevents the system from cleaning up this question.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン , I guess that is a pretty useless question to anybody else, not even searchable. I'll try to think harder about questions that shouldn't be committed to eternity and just ignore them or leave a comment for the OP. Thanks for the heads up...